# Where does the Foursquare notification come from?

Tags: notifications

Yesterday, I got a Foursquare friend request in the notifications panel.

The only running services at that time were, I believe, the same that are running now. Definitely there was *no Foursquare service* running. I hadn't used Foursquare in weeks. From *Settings:*

- Settings
- Google Services (GoogleLocationService)
- WhatsApp
- My Calendar
- Google Services (Cloud to Device Messa…, Google Messaging Ser…)
- Maps
- Android keyboard

I was logged into Google Latitude.

By what mechanism did the friend request reach the notifications panel?

Comment: Push notification, I expect. If you could only receive notifications from apps that are running there are a **lot** of notifications I'd be missing.

Comment: @AlEverett I wonder why Whatsapp is not using push notification. The Whatsapp service is quite heavy weight at 13MB!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Google Cloud Messaging receives a message from Google, it sends a *broadcast* to the related app. The app can receive this broadcast even if no *service* was running, and it can respond by starting a service, or by creating a notification from within the *broadcast receiver* itself.

[Part of the Android developers' documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#receiving) explains the process step-by-step. There's a lot of detail there that you only need to know to write an app that uses Google Cloud Messaging, but it might help satisfy your curiosity.

Comment: So Foursquare instructed Google to send a broadcast a message to the Foursquare app on my phone? Why call it *broadcast*, if it's only to one app? If you could outline the process step by step, then that would be great!

Comment: It's called a broadcast because the same mechanism is used within your phone to inform many apps of an event, such as connecting to a network. I wrote up [an explanation of services and broadcast receivers](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46096/12442) which may help.