# Is there an autorun or scheduler?

Tags: auto-start

I have an s3 mini.  It has an app called "My Galaxy" - a marketing adware kind of thing.  It runs without me launching it.  How is that done?  Is there a scheduler somewhere that launches this app?  Can I make changes to that scheduler?

I don't just want to stop "My Galaxy" (I could uninstall it), I want to know how it gets run automatically.

Comment: Maybe using a service? They can launch the app?

Comment: Can you disable this app in settings?

Comment: You cannot start manually.... It is started at specific broadcast intent..... You can only see it in Setting>Apps>Running..... And you can kill that background service...... There is nothing like autostart or scheduler in android....

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways in Android of scheduling things to happen later on certain conditions. One of them is the `AlarmManager`, which lets an app run at a predetermined time, or at a given interval between 15 minutes and daily. This is how most recurring tasks work on Android, such as checking email. There's no user-modifiable control for the `AlarmManager`: it's up to the app to expose appropriate settings.

Android apps can also register [broadcast receivers](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46096/12442) to be notified when certain conditions are met or when events happen. For example, the email app might also register a broadcast receiver to be triggered when an internet connection becomes available. That way, if it misses its times for checking email because you were offline, it can check email once you go back online.

Comment: And if all other apps lets you down, you always have automation apps like [Tasker](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=pVs7U5SFK4Teigf5soDwBQ&url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details%3Fid%3Dnet.dinglisch.android.taskerm&cd=2&ved=0CC8QFjAB&usg=AFQjCNER63-4xx9dD1tFai4R_cihBk79xA&sig2=ekumXGDIjUrsC_QssNSoUw).

Comment: I think it's worth being clear that Tasker uses these features of Android to let you define new tasks to run at intervals or when certain conditions are met. It doesn't let you control or override an app that uses alarms without offering any settings.

Answer (score -1):

Its not about startup or autostart.... You might have some application that is installed on your phone and you would have mistakenly given the right to run... Not an issue... just see the application name in Setting>Apps>Running and uninstall/Disable. Or if you want to do another thing just force stop and then clear application data fully. Then application cache will set to defaults. And you have give any right to execute it will ben revoked and your problem is resolved without harming the parent application.

**Another thing is that**, you cannot start an application natively, automatically... But yes there are some few apps in Play store that will automatically launch that application at scheduled event.

**Note**: *The launching of application is not same as that of the application running in background (background service). Background service is meant for some specific task to be done automatically that generally do not need any user input/intervention. You can launch application at scheduled time either by programming or installing third party scheduler app that will meet your needs. But you cannot start application's background service..... And technically its not of worth for you.*

Comment: This does not answer how to make new applications run automatically.

Comment: Talking from the developer point of view..... In android there is nothing like autostart or scheduler..... Application could have broadcast receiver that gets invoked automatically each time when specific event happens (Broadcast with specific intent). There the application starts automatically. This could be at some specific time, idle time, power on time, network status change, call event, message event etc.... etc... That you can only see in Setting>Apps>Running>Cached..... That is actually what, i was telling you.... If you are android developer then u will understand this point....