# Why does Facebook messenger stays active irrespective of the Mobile data being enabled or not

Tags: facebook-messenger

I have noticed that in my task manager Facebook Messenger stays active even thought the mobile data is enabled or dis-abled.

I have tried doing the force stop many times when the app is not at all required.Also visited the [site](http://lifehacker.com/5650894/android-task-killers-explained-what-they-do-and-why-you-shouldnt-use-them) for some solution.

But when I enable the mobile data I observe that FB messenger was active all the while in the background and I automatically get notifications without activating the app.
Any suggestion or help accepted.

Comment: "I automatically get notifications without activating the app" It doesn't follow that it must have been active all the time. Most apps that use Internet are set to start automatically when a connection becomes available.

Comment: @DanHulme Lets say for example I open the app check the notifications and then close it by "Back Button" as you say that some apps are set to start automatically for this I do the force class and the app closes from the task manager again upon receiving the connection I get the notifications by default

Comment: Yes, that sounds normal. Even after the app was closed, connecting to the internet [broadcasts an intent](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46096/12442) which can start the app again.