# Icon remains in drawer after removing stock app

Tags: root-access, uninstallation, system-apps, app-drawer

I removed Google Drive from system/app using Root Explorer. However, when I check the app drawer, the icon is still there. (When I removed other system apps like samsung's ChatOn, the icon disappeared).

I wish to remove other google apps I don't need/use, but I dont want to leave a bunch of nonfunctional icons in the drawer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you rebooted your device after removing the apk from `/system/app`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you restarted your device since removing the app? If you've simply deleted the .apk using Root Explorer then then it won't have performed the 'cleanup' that normally happens when uninstalling an application. Restarting your device should cause the app drawer to re-detect the installed apps and the icon should disappear.

[This](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/79336/30530) answer (relevant part quoted below) explains a bit about what happens when uninstalling an app 'properly', this won't have happened if you've simply removed the apk file.

> When you uninstall a package, it also removes other data to do with
>   that package: for example, the app's own private data, its data on the
>   SD card, your default preferences for that app. It also tells any
>   other interested apps that you've removed the app, via an intent
>   broadcast. Other apps receiving that broadcast might take further
>   action based on that: for example, a launcher (home screen app) would
>   remove desktop shortcuts and widgets from that app, since they won't
>   work any more.

Also, make sure you have checked /data/app as there may be another apk for Google Drive there if you have updated the app via the Play Store. If you remove the apk from here too (if it exists) then the icon should disappear. A reboot may still be required.

Comment: Hmm, here's the twist: google drive has two apks, one in /system/app which I had already moved. Then I found one in /data/app, so I moved that to my back up folder too. After restarting the phone, the icon finally disappeared :-)

Comment: Added this to my answer for the benefit of others seeing this question. I forgot that the apk sometimes exists in both locations.

Answer (score 0):

I had uninstalled system apps using 'Titanium Backup' and 'System App Remover(Root)', only to find that empty shell icons are left behind.

Deleting Home/App Launcher's data and cache did help in removing the icon from the app drawer.