# "Google BroadcastListener" running for over 78 hours now

Tags: google, audio-recording

On my Galaxy S3 I have "Google BroadcastListener" running for over 78 hours now... Is it possible my ex is accessing it or something?

[image: screenshot of active app]

Also, is this the reason my "record audio" won't work? It tells me that "Unable to start new recording. Other applications already recording", yet I have nothing else on that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

No. This listener has nothing to do with "listening" in the sound sense: it's listening for intent broadcasts, which are a kind of signal that different software components in the device use to notify each other of important events. For more explanation about broadcasts, see [What's the difference between a service and a broadcast receiver?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46096/12442)

If you want to solve the problem of not being able to record audio, I recommend you post a new question with full details about what steps you took, what happened, and how long this has been happening, along with what phone and OS version you have. Without any further details, my first guess would be that  if the audio recorder app you're using stopped unexpectedly, it failed to properly release the mic for use by other apps. In this case restarting the device would fix the problem.