# How can Android run a disabled application?

Tags: crashes, youtube, disable-app

I have just run into a situation described in [this blog](http://itfuckup.com/2018/03/29/youtube-is-disabled-but-not/):

[image]

Can any one explain this to me? How can Android run a disabled application? What good do we have from marking applications as disabled, if system is ignoring that?

How can I force Android to respect my will and to never execute a disabled app?

Comment: Related but no satisfactory answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/129427/96277