# Can disabled application influence / modify system and UI

Tags: applications, disable-app

This is somewhat a follow up to [my 1,5 year old question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/196360/20449) (still not answered).

I [already know](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/129427/20449) that applications displayed as disabled may still be running in background in certain scenarios (mostly, when Google says they must run). But is it a normal situation that such disabled application is modifying / interfering with the system or user interface?

I have Duo (another Google monster) disabled in my device:

[image]

Yet it clearly interfere with my system / user experience and it adds some new items to my contacts:

[image]

Is this a normal situation. And if so -- then what is "disabling an application" really mean? It seems to be a total fake, making Android users a pure idiots.

Comment: This is most likely the handiwork of your Contacts app working closely with data received from Google services. In my Contacts app the Duo call option appear only for contacts who have registered for that service. If you can, take backup of all of your contacts into a VCF file, remove all the  Google accounts from Settings > Accounts, clear data for Contacts and Contacts Provider/Storage, than add a number manually (not by loading VCF) and see if Duo option still appears (provided it appeared earlier to cross-check). Make sure you do all of this with all internet connectivities turned off.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed comment. The thing is that neither me nor any of my friends (and specially not the contact in the screenshot) are using Duo, because it is very unpopular here, where I live (Poland). I have never used it, run it or registered within it on any device. None of my friends are using Duo, as far as I am aware of. Above depicted contact is 99.99% not using Duo as well.